# Accessing field values in node--mycustomtype.tpl.php

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I have a content type that contains a field called headshot. This is a file field. In my custom node template file, I need to access the value of the headshot's filename property. `dpr($content)` produces this for the field:

```
[field_headshot] => Array
                        (
                            [und] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [fid] => 53
                                            [display] => 1
                                            [description] => 
                                            [uid] => 10
                                            [filename] => kanderson.jpg
                                            [uri] => public://headshot/kanderson.jpg
                                            [filemime] => image/jpeg
                                            [filesize] => 21669
                                            [status] => 1
                                            [timestamp] => 1337356962
                                            [type] => image
                                            [rdf_mapping] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [image_dimensions] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [width] => 180
                                                    [height] => 252
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )
```

I've tried

```
<img class="speaker_headshot" src="sites/default/files/styles/large/public/headshot/<?php print render($content['field_headshot'][0]['filename']); ?>" alt="<?php print $title; ?>" />
```

and

```
<img class="speaker_headshot" src="sites/default/files/styles/large/public/headshot/<?php print render($content['field_headshot']['filename']); ?>" alt="<?php print $title; ?>" />
```

with no success. How do I access this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a web-accessible URL for the file you need to use [`file_create_url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) on the field's `uri` property. You can also make use of [`theme_image()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) so you don't have to write the HTML yourself:

```
$vars = array(
  'path' => file_create_url($content['field_headshot'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']),
  'alt' => $title,
  'attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('speaker_headshot')
  )
);

$img = theme('image', $vars);

print $img;
```

Since this code will clutter up your template file you might want to consider putting in a preprocess function instead, something like:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->type == 'headshot') {
    $items = field_get_items('node', $vars['node'], 'field_headshot');
    $image = array_shift($items);

    $image_vars = array(
      'path' => file_create_url($image['uri']),
      'alt' => $vars['title'],
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('speaker_headshot')
      )
    );

    $vars['image'] = theme('image', $image_vars);
  }
}
```

Then in your template file you can just `print $image;` to get the HTML output.

Comment: Thank you, but that's more than I need to know! I just need to know how to access the VALUE of the filename attribute, and `$content['field_headshot'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['filename']` doesn't work either.

Comment: But just so that I could say I tried, I added your preprocess function to my template.php, and ended up with this error: `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /home/www/expo/modules/field/field.module on line 958`

Comment: Ah, sorry about that I get carried away :) `$content['field_headshot'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['filename']` is definitely the right variable if your output from `dpr($content)` is right above

Comment: I took a guess at your content type being called 'headshot' (it probably isn't), other than that I can't think of a good reason why you'd be getting that error

Comment: The output is correct; it's pasted directly from the node as rendered. But the variable you provide is NOT returning a value.

Comment: No, my content type is not called headshot. The content type is called speaker; it contains a file field called headshot.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say...you can see from the output that the value you're looking for is at `['field_headshot']['und'][0]['filename']`. If that output has come from a variable called `$content`, then logically your value has to be at `$content['field_headshot']['und'][0]['filename']`. It has nothing to do with Drupal, it's how PHP works

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But that's not what you suggested earlier - your suggestion had [LANGUAGE_NONE] instead of [und].

Comment: [`LANGUAGE_NONE`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_NONE/7). As you can see, `LANGUAGE_NONE == 'und'`. It's the same thing.

Comment: I don't know what else to do here. I tried just printing out the value of the variable, and it returns nothing. If I do dpr($content['field_headshot']), I still get ridiculous nested arrays and objects. I've created [link](http://drupalbin.com/21412) to show what that returns (too long to post in the OP here) - why would printing the value of a single field include ALL of the fields?

Comment: And it's strange, because I can access the value of the job title field with `print render($content['field_job_title'][0]);` - is field_headshot different because it's a file field type, rather than just text?

Comment: It will be different yeah...try `$content['field_headshot']['#items'][0]['filename']`, I think that'll do it according to the output on drupalbin